# How to change direction of pie diagram in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

Trying to change pie diagram direction from right-left, to left-right direction.
Now it looks like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
eye_color = {'blue':5,'green':10,'brown':20, 'black':15 }

sum([v for v in eye_color.values()])
P = [f/sum([v for v in eye_color.values()]) for f in eye_color.values()]
plt.pie(P, labels = [k for k in eye_color.keys()], startangle = 90, autopct = '%1.1f%%',
       shadow = True) 
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

How to show it like this, when first part angle degree going to a positive direction, right?:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html?highlight=pie#matplotlib.pyplot.pie), use

`counterclock=False`

Comment: You're welcome. If that solution resolved your problem, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)